# Need a "Simple" excel macro to find bottom cell in a column, create a range and copy it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet I'm using to compile text that changes all the time.

In column AD, Row 4(AD4) I put the contents of text, and it can have data going 1000 to 4000 rows down. It changes every time, so there is no static range name. I need a macro that

- finds the final piece of data in that column,
- then automatically "drags a box" from that spot two columns to the left (AB4)
- and copies it... (A 3000 row piece of text would be AB4:AD3004) (Macro stops there, with text to be copied highlighted)

The current version finds the bottom cell correctly, but if I run the macro a 2nd time, with new data, it keeps trying to copy the same range. (I used the Formula Define.Name method, to name the cell, and then selected AB4:LastRow) but it is ALWAYS 3160 whether data goes to row 4000 or not.....

```
Sub Last_row()
Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp).Select
' following lines of code are useless
Range("AB4:AD3160").Select
Range("AD3160").Activate
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: This is in MS Office Excel 2007. BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("AB4", .Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp)).Copy
End With
```

Copy to specific location **WITHOUT** using clipboard:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("AB4", .Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp)).Copy Sheet2.[A1]
End With
```

Copy and exclude formatting:

```
With Sheet1
    With .Range("AB4", .Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp))
        Sheet2.Cells(1, "A").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

**Note:** Replace all sheet codenames (sheet1, Sheet2) above with your actual sheet codenames.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code hard-codes the range of interest with
`Range("AB4:AD3160").Select`

This code will define a dynamic range starting from AB4 to the last non-empty cell in column AD

You can then use this range (without selecting) for changing values elsewhere (note that you may not need to actually *copy* `rng1`, it is possible to dump these values to a separate range directly without a copy and paste.

```
Sub Last_row()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range([ab4], Cells(Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp))
rng1.Copy
End Sub
```

**Update:** Example of how to copy a dynamic sized range from one sheet to another without a copy and paste:

```
Sub Last_row2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[ab4], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp))
    ws2.[a1].Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count).Value = rng1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old, but I just had a similar situation come up and determined a solution that met my needs and might be helpful to others that stumble across this.

Try using .End(xlDown) instead of .End(xlUp).

I had the same problem as described where I was trying to perform an autofill in column B with VBA based on the list of values in column A.  A subsequent run with a shorter list in column A would result in the autofill trying to populate B all the way down to the original last row of column A.

NOTE: xlDown may not work if you have blanks within your range of data.

Something like this:

```
Sub Last_row()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ADlastrow As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ADlastrow = ws.Range("AD4").End(xlDown).Row
Range("AB4:AD"&ADlastrow).select

Selection.copy
' optional - orig post claimed to want to just have
' text to be copied highlighted, but sample code 
' included the code to copy 
End sub
```